# Increasing the scroll speed - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jscrollpane

I am modifying a html5/jQuery video player for a site I am creating for somebody. So far everything is going smoothly. I have one small issue, the scrolling speed for the playlist moves very very slowly, here is the code;

```
/*! Copyright (c) 2011 Brandon Aaron (http://brandonaaron.net)
 * Licensed under the MIT License (LICENSE.txt).
 *
 * Thanks to: http://adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/ for some pointers.
 * Thanks to: Mathias Bank(http://www.mathias-bank.de) for a scope bug fix.
 * Thanks to: Seamus Leahy for adding deltaX and deltaY
 *
 * Version: 3.0.6
 * 
 * Requires: 1.2.2+
 */
(function(a){function d(b){var c=b||window.event,d=[].slice.call(arguments,1),e=0,f=!0,g=0,h=0;return b=a.event.fix(c),b.type="mousewheel",c.wheelDelta&&(e=c.wheelDelta/120),c.detail&&(e=-c.detail/3),h=e,c.axis!==undefined&&c.axis===c.HORIZONTAL_AXIS&&(h=0,g=-1*e),c.wheelDeltaY!==undefined&&(h=c.wheelDeltaY/120),c.wheelDeltaX!==undefined&&(g=-1*c.wheelDeltaX/120),d.unshift(b,e,g,h),(a.event.dispatch||a.event.handle).apply(this,d)}var b=["DOMMouseScroll","mousewheel"];if(a.event.fixHooks)for(var c=b.length;c;)a.event.fixHooks[b[--c]]=a.event.mouseHooks;a.event.special.mousewheel={setup:function(){if(this.addEventListener)for(var a=b.length;a;)this.addEventListener(b[--a],d,!1);else this.onmousewheel=d},teardown:function(){if(this.removeEventListener)for(var a=b.length;a;)this.removeEventListener(b[--a],d,!1);else this.onmousewheel=null}},a.fn.extend({mousewheel:function(a){return a?this.bind("mousewheel",a):this.trigger("mousewheel")},unmousewheel:function(a){return this.unbind("mousewheel",a)}})})(jQuery)
```

You can view the video player here;
http://design.jarethmusic.com/

As you can obviously see, the scrolling speed on the playlist is very slow, any ideas for sorting this out would be perfect.

Regards
John

Comment: It seems that all of your mouse wheel deltas (The speed of your mouse) is divided by 120.

Make a new variable called speed and set it to 10 or something smaller.   Then change any speed at 120 to your new variable, try that and return a comment

Comment: This isn't my code. I don't really understand jQuery tbh

Comment: Try this - Anywhere it says "/120" make it say "/10".  In almost any text editor, you can 'find and replace' all.  I would suggest doing find and replace as a temp solution just to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the code with this:

```
/*! Copyright (c) 2011 Brandon Aaron (http://brandonaaron.net)
 * Licensed under the MIT License (LICENSE.txt).
 *
 * Thanks to: http://adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/ for some pointers.
 * Thanks to: Mathias Bank(http://www.mathias-bank.de) for a scope bug fix.
 * Thanks to: Seamus Leahy for adding deltaX and deltaY
 *
 * Version: 3.0.6
 * 
 * Requires: 1.2.2+
 */
(function(a){function d(b){var c=b||window.event,d=[].slice.call(arguments,1),e=0,f=!0,g=0,h=0;return b=a.event.fix(c),b.type="mousewheel",c.wheelDelta&&(e=c.wheelDelta/10),c.detail&&(e=-c.detail/3),h=e,c.axis!==undefined&&c.axis===c.HORIZONTAL_AXIS&&(h=0,g=-1*e),c.wheelDeltaY!==undefined&&(h=c.wheelDeltaY/10),c.wheelDeltaX!==undefined&&(g=-1*c.wheelDeltaX/10),d.unshift(b,e,g,h),(a.event.dispatch||a.event.handle).apply(this,d)}var b=["DOMMouseScroll","mousewheel"];if(a.event.fixHooks)for(var c=b.length;c;)a.event.fixHooks[b[--c]]=a.event.mouseHooks;a.event.special.mousewheel={setup:function(){if(this.addEventListener)for(var a=b.length;a;)this.addEventListener(b[--a],d,!1);else this.onmousewheel=d},teardown:function(){if(this.removeEventListener)for(var a=b.length;a;)this.removeEventListener(b[--a],d,!1);else this.onmousewheel=null}},a.fn.extend({mousewheel:function(a){return a?this.bind("mousewheel",a):this.trigger("mousewheel")},unmousewheel:function(a){return this.unbind("mousewheel",a)}})})(jQuery)
```